# @Autowired объекты равны null

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, inversion-of-control

Когда запускается джоб, объекты с аннотацией `@Autowired` равны null.
Если метод вызывается например через контроллер, все работает гуд.

```
@Service
public class SegmentsDaoImpl implements SegmentsDao, Job {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    private Connection connection;

    @PostConstruct
    public void runJob() {
        JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(SegmentsDaoImpl.class)
                .withIdentity("myMethod", "Group-1").build();
        Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("myMethod", "Group-1")
                .withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withIntervalInMinutes(30).repeatForever()).build();
        try {
            Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
            if(!scheduler.checkExists(jobDetail .getKey()) && !scheduler.checkExists(trigger.getKey())) {
                scheduler.start();
                scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
            }
        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) throws JobExecutionException {
        myMethod();
    }

    public void myMethod() {
        ...
        connection = dataSource.getConnection();    //dataSource = null если метод вызван джобом
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Скорее всего Spring здесь не причем -- я не знаю что это за джобы у вас такие, но, видимо, они как-то создают этот класс сами в обход спринга.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему решил! Создал отдельный класс `UtilsApplicationContext` в котором инициализируется объект `DataSource`.
Потом в методе `execute` мы просто вызываем метод который возвращает нам синициализированный объект - `DataSource`:

```
@Override
public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) throws JobExecutionException {
    if (dataSource == null) {
        dataSource = UtilsApplicationContext.getDataSource();
    }
    myMethod();
}
```

Пример кода класса который возвращает `DataSource`:

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Component
public class UtilsApplicationContext implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext context;
    private static DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        context = applicationContext;
        dataSource = (DataSource) context.getBean("dataSource");
    }

    /**
     * @return DataSource
     */
    public static DataSource getDataSource() {
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring - это контейнер, который предоставляет различные услуги, например - CDI (Context Dependency Injection), в вашем примере это представлено аннотацией `@Autowired`. Бывают случаи, когда развёртывание контейнера Spring осуществляется под управлением другого Java EE контейнера, например сервера приложений JBoss/Wildfly, который тоже предоставляет различные сервисы, например, `@PostConstruct`. Контейнеры не интегрированы друг с другом, поэтому `@PostConstruct`, выполненный JBoss-ом ничего не знает о Spring-овом `@Autowired`. Если у Вас именно такая ситуация, то это - архитектурная ошибка.

Вы можете попытаться использовать другие аннотации, например, для инъекции `DataSource` применить `@Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/datasources/MyDS")`. Если в приложении развёрнута реализация JPA, то можно заменить `DataSource` на `EntityManager` и работать с БД через него:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "myUnit")
private EntityManager em;
```